# JQuery Dialog, part over, part under Flash video

Tags: jquery, flash, user-interface, dialog

Topics related to this have been discussed, usually with the suggestion that Flash content should have wmode set to opaque (I believe that's done and not the problem here).

In my case, part of the JQuery dialog is above and part is below.  Obviously it's possible for stuff to appear on top of the flash video (because part already is), but I don't know why most of it appears under the Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using

`<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` and `wmode="transparent"` in your `<embed>` / `<object>` element creating the flash file.

This should fix your problem with z-index.

Comment: I've tried both transparent and opaque, with the same results. But again, the fact that part of the dialog appears over top of the Flash would seem to indicate that it's not a problem with the Flash, but is instead a problem with the dialog.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I've figured it out.  YouTube was using <embed> before but has switched to using iFrame.  To set the wmode for the Flash within a YouTube iFrame, you can pass wmode=transparent in the iFrame URL.  Still not sure why some content appeared above the Flash before while the rest was below, seems like a jQuery Dialog bug...